# docker compose up nginx reverse proxy not adding containers to docker0 bridge

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, bridge

After I carry out `docker-compose up`, it starts the containers.
when I do `docker ps` I get the below, which tells me that the containers are running. However when I do `docker network inspect bridge` the result shows me that there are no containers part of the `docker0` bridge.

When I then carry out docker run `meanchat_myserver` it actually does show up on `docker0` and I am also getting the data that the server is running on `port 3000`. 
Which I don't get by using `docker-compose`.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am reading that when I use `docker0` I can only refer to IP's to connect to other containers and not the name. Can I assume the ip's don't change on the containers and that this works without issue on deploying the app in production?

```
  02cf08b1c3da        d57f06ba9c68        "npm start"              33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       4200/tcp             meanchat_client_1
  e257063c9e21        meanchat_myserver   "npm start"              33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       3000/tcp             meanchat_myserver_1
  02441c2e43f5        e114a298eabd        "npm start"              About an ago         Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   meanchat_nginx_1
  88d9841d2553        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          27017/tcp            meanchat_mongo_1
```

compose

```
version: '3'

services:
# Build the container using the client Dockerfile
    client:
        build: ./
        # This line maps the contents of the client folder into the container.
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app

    myserver:
        build: ./express-server
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
        depends_on:
            - mongo

    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        # Map Nginx port 80 to the local machine's port 80
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        # Link the client container so that Nginx will have access to it

    mongo:
        environment:
            - AUTH=yes
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=superAdmin
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin123
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=d0c4ae452a5c
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - /var/mongodata/data:/data/db
```

Comment: You mean `$docker network inspect bridge -f "{{.Containers}}"` returns empty?

Comment: yes after compose up it shows empty, When i manually run the images they show up in the bridge. Is that normal behaviour?

Comment: so Right now, I removed all containers. Docker ps is empty. I am now running docker-compose up -d --build --remove-orphans Successfully built cfb1f18e9c0c
Successfully tagged meanchat_myserver:latest
Starting meanchat_nginx_1 ...
Starting meanchat_client_1 ...
Starting meanchat_mongo_1 ...
Starting meanchat_nginx_1
Starting meanchat_client_1
Starting meanchat_mongo_1 ... done
Creating meanchat_myserver_1 ...
Starting meanchat_client_1 ... done   then docker network inspect bridge etc. returns empty.  When I do docker ps and then run one of the images it shows up when inspect bridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app.

For more detail, refer this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

This means `containers` with `compose` won't be located in default `bridge network` by default.

You can check which network the `containers` with `compose` are using with the command.

```
docker inspect $container_name -f "{{.NetworkSettings.Networks}}"
```

However, If you want `containers` to be in default `bridge network`, you can use [network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode).

```
services:
    service_name:
        # other options....
        network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: docker inspect meanchat_client -f "{{.NetworkSettings.Networks}}"

Template parsing error: template: :1:18: executing "" at <.NetworkSettings.Net...>: map has no entry for key "NetworkSettings" when I refer to    let url = 'http://myserver:3000/api/register';   in my register component it gives me a p://myserver:3000/api/register net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when I use the ip  of the container instead of the name myserver it times out.

Comment: When I do netstat -a, it doesn't show port 3000 or 4200. Is that correct TCP    0.0.0.0:80             mine-PC:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            mine-PC:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            mine-PC:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2179           mine-PC:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           mine-PC:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          mine-PC:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          mine-PC:0              LISTENING?

Comment: docker network ls now does show me the default network. App_default 
When I inspect this network I see indeed my 4 containers. When I do a dock exec ping from the server to the client this seems to work. Yet I can't refer to the names of the Containers, gives me a resolve error.

Comment: Usually, `docker` doesn't assign intact container name as the alias. If you want to assign a specific alias to containers, you can use [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases).

Comment: how should I make the http call to the server container, is it normal to use aliases instead of ip, where can I read this? And how do I figure out if the mongo image is working? I can't seem to login to the mongo image.

Comment: Between containers within the same network, I usually use alias I set because I think it is more flexible and easy to remember but of course you can also use `IP` since `IP` also can be set as what you specify.(refer this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address)). However, when it comes to `swarm-mode`, `IP` seems not to work properly as I know. that is why I prefer to use an alias instead of IP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162688/discussion-between-oudekaas-and-sangminkim).